# measure similarity between 1 dimensional vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, similarity

**EDITED QUESTION**

I have n signals of equal length.

```
    X_signal
    Y_signal
    ...
    Z_signal
```

I calculate minima of these signals and I store their location (in time) in the vectors

```
X = [x1 x2 x3 x4 ... x100]
Y = [y1 y2 y3 y4 ... y150]
...
Z = [z1 z2 z3 z4 ... z110]
```

You can think about X,Y,..Z as time series that can have different lenght.
I assume that the original signals are similar if they have their minima almost at the same locations.

I would like to know what would be a smart approach to measure this kind of similarity keeping in mind that some minima in X,Y,Z can be just noise.

For example if X = [1 5 8 12 15 20] and Y = [1.5 5.5 7.5 10 12 15.5 20.2] they should be similar since almost all the points have the same value exept for Y(4) = [10].

If you have time code or pseudo code in Matlab is appreciated, otherwise also a suggestion, link etc. is super fine.

Thanks

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I have n vectors of different length.

```
X = [x1 x2 x3 x4 ... x100]
Y = [y1 y2 y3 y4 ... y150]
...
Z = [z1 z2 z3 z4 ... z110]
```

Vectors (X Y ... Z) represent minima values of the energy of the corresponding signals (X_energy, Y_energy, etc).

To recap starting from the signals X_signal, Y_signal ... Z_signal I compute the energy in windows of 20 samples and I calculate the minima of the resulting energy signals.

Assuming that 2 or more vector are similar if they have almost equal values (i.e. X and Y are similar if x1 ~= y1, x2 ~=y2, etc.) In other words I assume that the original signals are similar if they have minimum energy at the same (or almost at the same) time instant. I would like to know what would be a smart approach to measure this kind of similarity.

PS.

1. It is almost impossible that two vectors are equal so I would like to have just an idea of how close their "points" are.
2. X and Y could be similar also if they are shifted (i.e. x1~=y3, x2=~y4, etc)
3. It is always the case that the values are in ascending order `(x1<x2<...<x100)`

If you have time code or pseudo code in Matlab is appreciated, otherwise also a suggestion, link etc. is super fine.

Thanks

Comment: Would [Mahalanobis distance](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/mahal.html) work? It's just a suggestion from the top of my head.

Comment: What approach to have when vectors are of different lengths ? Find a subvector that match ? For instance find [3 7 8] in [1 4 5 **3 7 8** 6 7 8] but ponderate it because it would be less similar than [3 7 8 6 7] ... seems [xcorr](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html) can go but being careful for all different sizes ... well that's a first idea..

Comment: @CitizenInsane thanks, I will try with xcorr. just a remark (I also edited the question). The values of the vectors are ordered in ascending order...you can think about them as a time series

Comment: While Mahalanobis distance as suggested by @kkuilla does not consider for time shifts, it is interesting to read for metrics in [`pdist`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html) and results formating in [`squareform`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/squareform.html)

Comment: @CitizenInsane Ah, I missed the time sequence bit.Then correlation is probably the best bet. It is interesting to read  though that `pdist` is so versatile.

Comment: Since you are interested in similarity in the exact value of each entry, colinearity does not seem to be what you are trying to assess. Instead you can take the difference between the vectors to compute the rms or mean(abs(diff)).

Comment: Hi Thanks to all of you. I edited again the question to provide more info since I think that the problem was not clear enough. I think that the solution of @TryHard would be the most appropriate, but it should be robust to noise values in between 2 equal points. What I mean is that if X = [1 4 7 10] and Y = [1 2 4 7 9.9 10] those 2 vectors should be similar since the points [1 4 7 10] match and [2 9.9] could be considered noise.

Comment: I updated my answer from updates in question and comments we had.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach (particularly if you do not have the Statistics and/or Signal Processing toolbox) is to generate a correlation matrix for all of your vectors with the Matlab function **corrcoef**

Since your vectors are different sizes, you would have to either

- zero pad the smaller vectors so they are the same size as the largest
- Or take  an aligned sample of values less than or equal to the number
  of values in the smallest vector,  out of each of them before
  computing correlation.

It depends on your application which procedure is more suitable. Since your vectors are ordered in ascending order, likely zero padding would be inappropriate.

Then you would need to create a matrix  M with the rows corresponding to the elements, and the columns corresponding to each (zero padded or sampled) vector.

You could do that with the Matlab  function **horzcat**:

```
M=horzcat(V1,V2,...Vn)
```

where V1, V2, ..Vn are each column vectors of the same size.

Finally you could get a correlation matrix for all of your vectors with  **corrcoef**:

```
Cmat=corrcoef(M)
```

Matlab docs for corrcoef at [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html) will help you understand how to interpret the results statistically.

Note that this approach would not take into account any correlation between lagged versions of your vectors.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but `corrcoef` is for zeroth lag only and *X and Y could be similar also if they are shifted (i.e. x1~=y3, x2=~y4, etc)* ... it's also based on covariance,so amplitude shifted signals will match and maybe it is not what @gabboshow wants

Comment: It is true that corrcoef would work only for zero lags- the OP would need to create lagged versions of their vectors as well to use that approach. It isn't clear if amplitude shifting does or doesn't matter to the OP. This question could turn into a tutorial on time series analysis.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited answer**

Now that it is clear that `X` vector is the time positions of all minima of signal 'X', `Y` vector is the time positions of all minima of signal 'Y', etc... Here is some updated code.

In fact the idea is still the same ... we build a linearly sampled time vector from all time positions of the minima in all signals (+ from some time sampling precision)... then we build new signals being *1.0* everywhere expect at minima time locations (set to *0.0*) ... finally we use the same correlation code as before.

NB Speed and memory optimized version is now available [here](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/dce8d0767a7b69112e76)

```
function [RMax] = MinimaCorrelation(c, ts)
%[
    % Some default resolution and time-location of minima positions
    if (nargin < 2), ts = 0.1; end
    if (nargin < 1), c = { [1 3 8 7 3 4 12]; [3 8 7 3]; [4 12]; [5 3 8 -3 12]; [1 3 8 7 3 4 12]; }; end

    % Number of channels
    n = length(c);

    % Build linearly sample time vector for all time locations
    minTime = min(cellfun(@min, c));
    maxTime = max(cellfun(@max, c));
    timeVector = minTime:ts:maxTime;
    timeVector(end+1) = timeVector(end) + ts; % just to really include min and max if step is not ok

    % Build new signals being '1' everywhere except at minima locations (set to '0')
    s = ones(n, length(timeVector));
    for ni = 1:n
        for mv = c{ni}
            [~, ind] = min(abs(timeVector - mv));
            s(ni, ind) = 0;
        end
    end

    % Correlation (copied 3 times to avoid biased effect on sides ==> circular shifting is ok this way)
    s = [s, s, s].';
    RMax = max(xcorr(s, 'coeff'), [], 1);

    % Put in R(i,j) format
    RMax = reshape(RMax, [n n]);
%]
end
```

With default data, one obtains:

```
1.0000    0.9899    0.9866    0.9829    1.0000
0.9899    1.0000    0.9833    0.9865    0.9899
0.9866    0.9833    1.0000    0.9832    0.9866
0.9829    0.9865    0.9832    1.0000    0.9829
1.0000    0.9899    0.9866    0.9829    1.0000
```

Careful, it is brute force solution (time & memory consumption increases quickly with the number of signal and time resolution to have). Now that question is more clear, maybe someone will find smarter answer.

**Original answer**

Here is coarse-code for an approach using the maximum of [cross-correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) and [`xcorr`](http://cens.ioc.ee/local/man/matlab/toolbox/signal/xcorr.html) routine *(in signal processing toolbox)*:

```
function [RMax] = xcorrmax(c)
%[
    % Default signals for test
    if (nargin < 1),
        c = cell(0,0);
        c{end+1} = [1 3 8 7 3 4 12];
        c{end+1} = [3 8 7 3];
        c{end+1} = [4 12];
        c{end+1} = [5 3 8 -3 12];
        c{end+1} = [1 3 8 7 3 4 12];
    end

    % Number of channels
    n = length(c);

    % Padding to have vectors all of the same length
    % See also `padarray` to do circular/symmetric padding (i don't have image toolbox)
    maxlength = max(cellfun(@length, c));
    c = cellfun(@(x)myquickpad(x, maxlength), c, 'UniformOutput', false);
    c = cell2mat(c.').';

    % Compute cross correlation (multichannel case) and keep max value
    % NB1: May also use xcov if signal mean is not important
    % NB2: Normalization at lag = 0
    RMax = max(xcorr(c, 'coeff'), [], 1);

    % Put in R(i,j) format
    RMax = reshape(RMax, [n n]);
%]
end
function [a] = myquickpad(a, maxlength)
%[
    if (length(a) < maxlength)
        a(maxlength) = 0;
    end
%]
end
```

For the following signals:

```
(1) [1 3 8 7 3 4 12]
(2) [3 8 7 3]
(3) [4 12]
(4) [5 3 8 -3 12]
(5) [1 3 8 7 3 4 12]
```

It returns the following correlation matrix R(i,j) between `ith` and `jth` signals:

```
1.0000    0.6698    0.7402    0.8016    1.0000
0.6698    1.0000    0.8012    0.4853    0.6698
0.7402    0.8012    1.0000    0.6587    0.7402
0.8016    0.4853    0.6587    1.0000    0.8016
1.0000    0.6698    0.7402    0.8016    1.0000
```

Some remarks:

- It looks coherent, for instance signal (1) and (5) are identical and correlation is *1.0*.
- Because of normalization used it considers (1) closer to (3) than (2) ... so should be reviewed upon your needs (see normalization as in `xcorrcoef` for instance as shown by @paisanco).
- You can use `xcov` instead of `xcorr` if signal shifts in amplitude are not important.
- Again, this is a coarse approach, not speed/memory optimized at all, nor accounting for the fact that values are sorted, and may be not fully inline with what you'd really like to have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I am not sure that it fits my case, mostly because I was not totally clear in my question. Please have a look at the edited one. I hope you can help me.

Comment: @gabboshow It is not clear what you call minima ... do you mean that for each signal Si you have Ni observations and you store  all minima in a sorted MSi vector (that thus can be of different lengths for each signal) ?

Comment: @Citizenlnsane yes exactly. The values of the MSi vector are the "time locations" of the minima of the signal Si.

Comment: @gabboshow I think we're not in line ... I think you're telling X_signal is single observation and has multiple minima at time-positions given by X=[x1 x2 ... X110]   ... then Y_signal has other multiple minima at time-positions given by Y=[y1, y2, ....Y150], etc... was not the same for what I was thinking.

Comment: @Citizenlnsane Sorry if I still was not clear. X_signal is a 1 dimension signal function of time, X is the vector containig the position of the minima. I think your last comment clarified the misunderstanding.

Comment: thanks again for your solution. It is a smart approach,  but with my data I get always very high correlations between all the signals (always >0.99). I tried to decrease ts to 0.05, but still signals very correlated. with 0.01 I run out of memory.

Comment: @gabboshow So may be you can unvectorize things to work pair by pair only, and use some custom correlation function ... see this [pseudo-code](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/4bed854804330737eb78) using [`mod`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) to do circular shift with any resolution as an example.

Comment: @gabboshow For information I pushed speed-optimized code [here](https://gist.github.com/CitizenInsane/dce8d0767a7b69112e76). It is really fast even for large number of minima and small time resolution. Hope you'll like it.